# Can I use a photo in which we can see a known logo on my website?

Tags: images, legal, trademark

I took a cityscape picture that I intend to use on my website. In the picture, we can see a recognizable logo (let's say a famous hotel chain) and I was wondering if it could cause any legal issue?

It's a commercial website, but my business has nothing to do with the logo that can be seen in the picture.

Comment: I think it's more general legal question than related to Pro Webmasters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not generally. However, if the logo appears large enough to give the wrong impression, then I would not use the photo unless you can create a logo for your site and possibly place it over the other logo making it clear that the two are not the same. You do not have to cover the logo completely, just enough to give the right idea.